# vue.js webpack and static images (without vuecli and nodejs dev server)

Tags: django, vue.js, webpack, static

I have a vue.js Single File Component where I'd like to reference an image in an src tag.

Something like this :

```
 <img class="mr-4" v-if="item.picture_file" v-bind:src="item.picture_file">
 <img class="mr-4" v-else src="./idavatar.png">
```

I've read about webpack file-loader. So I added this in my webpack config file.

```
{
    test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
    use: [ 
      {
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          emitFile: true,
        },
      }
    ]
  }
```

If I put a the image file in my entry directory, it is processed then outputed in the output directory. Like other js files.

But then, when inspecting the web page :

[image]

I do not user vuecli or npm dev server. I use `Django` and embed the vuejs app in a template.

Most examples I read explain it should be outputed in an asset directory, that - i guess - is served via npm dev server.

How could I finally serve this file?

Maybe, there is a way to embed it in the build? I did play with the emit option, hoping it would be merged withe the main.js in /dist ... but nope. It's just not created on disk.

Thanks for reading !

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [Django Webpack loader](https://github.com/owais/django-webpack-loader), since you're using django and webpack.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, I solved my issue with a simple hack.

I looked in some of my view page source in the browser and noted the path served for other classical django static assets.

It should be something like : `/static/<name-of-the-app>/img`

And then inserted in my component :

```
<img class="mr-4" v-if="item.picture_file" v-bind:src="item.picture_file">
<img class="mr-4" v-else src="/static/<name-of-the-app>/img/default-avatar.png">
```

So no webpack tweaking needed anymore, just using the Django static file serving.